# Swapping the nibbles in a char element

Tags: c++, c

What are nibbles in a char element?

How do we swap them?

Can anyone explain the swapping of the nibbles with an example:

Comment: The proposed duplicate question is a little erratic; it has answers for 16-bit and 32-bit nibble swapping — and a link to the [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) which is a valuable resource.  I'm not sure whether it qualifies as 'exact duplicate', though it is certainly closely related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nibbles (or nybbles, by analogy with byte vs bite) are 4-bit chunks of a `char`.

You can swap them with:

```
c = ((c & 0x0F) << 4) | ((c & 0xF0) >> 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int x =  0xab; // 1010 1011 

int x1 = ( x & 0xF0) ; // 1010 0000
int x2 = ( x & 0x0F) ; // 0000 1011

x = ( x2 << 4 | x1 >> 4 ) ; // 1011 1010
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char temp1,temp2,z;// your o/p
temp1=((x & 0x0f)<<4);//x  be your input
temp2=((x & 0xf0)>>4);
z=temp1|temp2;
```